# Proof that the inverse of $f(x)={10}^x$ is $f^{-1}\left(x\right)={\mathrm{log} x\ }$.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function, elementary-functions

I know that the inverse of $f(x)={10}^x$ is $f^{-1}\left(x\right)={\mathrm{log} x\ }$, geometrically this implies reflecting the original function across the line y=x. I am also aware that this can be demonstrated algebraically by finding the inverse.

However, I'm curious as to how we can prove that the inverse $f(x)={10}^x$ is, in fact, $f^{-1}\left(x\right)={\mathrm{log} x\ }$.
Is there a method that can be used to demonstrate this? Any suggestions, methods, or explanations would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: What definitions for $10^x$ and $\log(x)$ are you using? In some contexts $\log(x)$ is simply defined as the inverse of the exponential function so there's nothing to prove

Comment: Once $10^x$ is shown to be invertible, $\log_{10}(x)$ is usually *defined* to be its inverse, so any "proof" of your claim will be trivial in nature. However, if you define $\log_{10}$ in another, but equivalent fashion, like $\log_{10}(x)=\frac{\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt}{\int_1^{10} \frac{1}{t}dt}$, things get more interesting. Of course, in order to construct the proof, you'll need to supply a definition of $10^x$.

Comment: How about the log calculation rules? $f^{-1}(f(x))=\log(10^x)=x\log 10=x\cdot 1=x$, showing that we get identity, confirming that it is indeed the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $10^{x+y}=10^x10^y$ and $10^y>1$ for $y>0$ it is straightforward that $f$ is a strictly increasing function, and therefore has an inverse $f^{-1}$ which is well defined (on $\mathbb R^{+*}$).

As said in the comments depending on your definitions, there might be nothing to prove at all, but let's adopt the morphism point of view consisting in proving that if $f$ is an exponential (maps addition to multiplication) then $f^{-1}$ is a logarithm (maps multiplication to addition).

It suffice then to end the argument by identifying $10$ as the characteristic element of both functions ($10^1=10$ and $\log(10)=1$).

Since the inverse is well defined, let call $a=f^{-1}(x)$ and $b=f^{-1}(y)$

$f^{-1}(xy)=f^{-1}(f(a)f(b))=f^{-1}(f(a+b))=a+b=f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y)$ as desired.